# Merge one table to another

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a table lets say 
Table1 with columns Point_ID, Size, Age, Dist, Treatment
and Table 2 with columns  Point_ID, Size, Age, Dist, Treatment, Path, Location.
Table 2 has similar data for Point_ID, Size, Age, Dist, Treatment as Table1 for some values.

I want to merge extra columns of Table 2 in Table1 such that there is no duplication and the resulted table looks likes  "Point_ID, Size, Age, Dist, Treatment, Path, Location."
There is data in Table1 in columns Point_ID, Size, Age, Dist, Treatment which does not have path and location, so the path and location should be null for them.
What SQL query to be performed?.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Point_ID` is a primary key or unique key shared by the two tables, then you can do this to create a new table `Table3` with the data you specified:

```
CREATE TABLE Table3 AS 
  SELECT t1.Point_ID, t1.Size, t1.Age, t1.Dist, t1.Treatment, t2.Path, t2.Location
  FROM Table1 t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Point_ID = t2.Point_ID
  UNION 
  SELECT Point_ID, Size, Age, Dist, Treatment, Path, Location 
  FROM Table2;
```

For any row with `Point_ID` in `Table1` that doesn't exist in `Table2` the `Path` and `Location` columns will be NULL. If it does exist, the `Path` and `Location` columns will have the values from `Table2`. For any row with `Point_ID` in `Table2` that doesn't exist in `Table1`, the whole row will be added to the new table `Table3`.

Comment: That does not seem to work. Is there any other way?. The columns from table 2 were not added to this new table.

Comment: I've modified the query a bit so that it includes rows in Table2 not found in Table1. That should at least help some.